# Laravel 8 Relation not working on null object but the relationship isn't null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have relation Products and to their related Products. Output shows the relation actually exists but the blade breaks. There is something I'm missing but I don't know what. Can you help?

Here is the ProductsRelations model:

```
...
class ProductsRelations extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='products_relations';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id'
      , 'product_id'
      , 'relation'

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [];

    /**
     * Relations belong to Products relationship
     */

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Relations belong to Products relationship
     */

    public function relation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'relation', 'id');
    }
...
```

Here is the Products model:

```
...
class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='products';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
      , 'summary'
      , 'client_id'
      , 'category_id'
      , 'price'
      , 'seo_keywords'
      , 'seo_descriptions'
      , 'body'
      , 'published'
      , 'featured'
      , 'bestselling'
      , 'in_stock'
      , 'slug'
      
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [];
    
    protected $visible = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'published'=>'boolean'
      , 'featured'=>'boolean'
      , 'bestselling'=>'boolean'
      , 'in_stock'=>'boolean'
      
    ];


    /**
     * Products belong to Clients relationship
     */
    
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Clients::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Products belong to Categories relationship
     */
    
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductsCategories::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
...
```

Here is what I'm using on the Controller:

```
...
return view('home.relations.index')
            ->with('relations', ProductsRelations::class)
            ->with('active_count',
                ProductsRelations::where([
                    'client_id'=>auth()->user()->client_id
                ])->count()
            )
            ->with('records',
                ProductsRelations::query()
                    ->with(['product'=>function($query)
                    {   
                        $query->select('id', 'title');
                    }])
                    ->with(['relation'=>function($query)
                    {   
                        $query->select('id', 'title');
                    }])
                    ->where(['client_id'=>auth()->user()->client_id])
                    ->get()
            );
...
```

This is a part of what I get once outputted:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\ProductsRelations {#304 ▼
      #table: "products_relations"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #hidden: []
      #casts: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 46
        "client_id" => 1
        "product_id" => 181
        "relation" => 190
        "created_at" => "2022-05-24 10:23:49"
        "updated_at" => "2022-05-24 10:23:49"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "product" => App\Models\Products {#311 ▼
          #table: "products"
          #fillable: array:13 [▶]
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #casts: array:4 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          +preventsLazyLoading: false
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
          #attributes: array:2 [▼
            "id" => 181
            "title" => "2427 Dickens Haven"
          ]
          #original: array:2 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #classCastCache: []
          #attributeCastCache: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        "relation" => App\Models\Products {#314 ▼
          #table: "products"
          #fillable: array:13 [▶]
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #casts: array:4 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          +preventsLazyLoading: false
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
          #attributes: array:2 [▼
            "id" => 190
            "title" => "388 Torp Throughway Suite 364"
          ]
          #original: array:2 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #classCastCache: []
          #attributeCastCache: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
```

What am I missing please, can you pin-point it out to me.

Comment: Can you show blade and error as well?

Comment: This is the line that breaks, within a SELECT foreach() loop: <option value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->product->title }}</option> If I try {{ $option->relation->title }} it complains, thanks!

Comment: Yes very cool, how about you add that part to the question and tell us the error instead of "it complains". Because that's the part we already figured out, now we want to know about what it complains aka post the error messages.

Comment: The error: it complains: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel8\ecommware\admin\resources\views\home\relations\index.blade.php) Thanks!

Comment: The Laravel error screen highlights the line and that's all: <option value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->product->title }} {{ $option->relation->title }}</option> there isn't that much else to go on sorry.

Comment: And you're looping through `ProductRelations` or through `Products`. Try fetching the data first and then returning the view with that data instead of `return view(..)->with().`

Comment: Thanks, I did a dd() and posted the output above which is the ProductsRelations model having the collection used in the foreach().

Comment: Yeah I got that, but how you're passing data to your view is not the common way of doing it for full datasets, it's recommended for small pieces of data. As docs state, try passing data as follows: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#creating-the-first-available-view